# Resharper ConcurrentBag<T> AssignNullToNotNull, but not with List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, resharper, ienumerable

i have an understanding problem with `ConcurrentBag<T>` and `List<T>` as an underlaying collection to store some values.

I'm writing a class that should be enumerable and i want to iterate over the underlaying `ConcurrentBag<T>`, but ReSharper tell me that `return _items.GetEnumerator();` is:

> Possible 'null' assignment to entity marked with 'NotNull' attribute

What is the reason for this?

Code example:

```
public class MyClass : IEnumerable<Item> {
    private readonly ConcurrentBag<Item> _items;

    public MyClass() {
        _items = new ConcurrentBag<Item>();
    }

    public IEnumerator<Item> GetEnumerator() {
        if(_items == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Error.");
        return _items.GetEnumerator(); // AssignNullToNotNull
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

ReSharper tells me that everything is fine with:

- `List<T>` instead of `ConcurrentBag<T>`.
- `return ((IEnumerable<ITranslationItem>)_items).GetEnumerator();`

Is something wrong with my approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your approach.  This is caused by ReSharper's external annotations.  `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` is marked with `[NotNullAttribute]`.  However, the `ConcurrentBag<T>` implementation of `IEnumerable` isn't.

ReSharper sees that `MyClass.GetEnumerator()` must not be null and raises the warning when it sees that `_items.GetEnumerator()` doesn't have that same constraint.

You can either

1. "Suppress inspection for "Possible 'null' assignment [...] with comment"

   ```
   // ReSharper disable AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
       return _items.GetEnumerator(); // AssignNullToNotNull
   // ReSharper restore AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
   ```
2. Change `_items` to `private readonly IEnumerable<Item> _items`
3. Add a null-check on `_items.GetEnumerator()`

   ```
   IEnumerator<Item> retVal = _items.GetEnumerator();
   if (retVal == null)
       throw new InvalidOperationException("Error.");
   return retVal;
   ```